# How to add a comment to a source field in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

How do I add a comment to a Field in the Layer Properties - Source Fields tab?
The [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#source-fields-properties) says "Comments can be added by clicking in the comment field of the column ...", but clicking in the Comment Field or the Alias does not work.

However, I may add an Alias using the Attributes Form.

Example: Adding "Dato" as an Alias.
[image]
[image]

But, how may I add a comment (no. "Kommentar")?
I see Comment below Alias in the Attributes Form window, but the "text field" is missing?

Comment: For QGis 2.18 double-click allows me to add a comment. Attributeditor-dropdown at the top-middle is set to "automatic", python-init at the top-right is empty.

Comment: @Erik Lohmann, I need to use ver. 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A feature request has already been submitted for this issue:

[Issue report #18411](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18411)

---

At the moment, the only way to add comments is during field creation. But the comments are not saved. This is mentioned in the link by one the main developers, [Matthias Kuhn](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9839/matthias-kuhn):

> ... there is an editable field but its content is discarded right away and nowhere saved to. So IMO this is a GUI bug fix that it's now readonly and adding comments would be a feature request.

Comment: I had my suspicion. Thanks for the link to the bug-report site. I'll remember to look there if I bump into more strange things in the future.

Comment: @9ls1 - Most welcome! Hopefully they'll add this feature :)