# QGIS/Python: No comment added to attribute table when using layer.dataProvider().addAttributes

Tags: pyqgis

When adding attributes using the following methods and arguments, everything works correctly BUT not comment is shown in the source section of the layer's properties.

Why is this?

How can add the comment using Python in QGIS?

```
layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("somename", QVariant.String,"String",20,0,"Why does this comment not show up?!")])
```

[image: comments section for source in properties]

Comment: This post could be relevant: [How to add a comment to a source field in QGIS 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286920/how-to-add-a-comment-to-a-source-field-in-qgis-3)