# How do I format a comment for a layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, postgresql

I have a layer from a PostgreSQL database which has comments for certain columns. I can add them in PostgreSQL and get updated comments as

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN myschema.mytable.field1
    IS' My comment with 
a new Line'
```

However when I load "mytable" to QGIS I will see no new line.
I've tried to add '\n' which did not yield any meaningful results.

Can I format the comment in PostgreSQL in such a way, that I get a formatted comment in QGIS with multiple lines?

I've read [this question about comments](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/286920/81214) but it does not help me with finding a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping the string with `E` before it to protect the new line (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949768/how-to-insert-new-line-in-postgresql for more discussion).

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN myschema.mytable.field1
    IS E' My comment with \n a new Line'
```

Comment: More about PostgreSQL string constants with escapes here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html